# Ninject inject to winform after form creation?

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, dependency-injection, ninject

Im beginning to learn about dependency injection and have decided to try to build my own (simple) logging facade as an introduction to it. So far I have the logging facade working with the basic functionality of NLog and log4net using Ninject.
(I know that Ninject has its own logging facade, but this is a learning exercise)

However I have run into a problem. What I want to do is to replicate what I log to file in a RichTextBox (Im using winforms). I am able to do this using NLog and log4net directly. The problem I have is that when Ninject wires up the interfaces it creates an implementation of a logger before the richtextbox on my winform has been created and consequently the logger does not find the richtextbox.

What I think I need to do is create the form then get Ninject to create the logger and inject it into the form, but I have no idea how to do this. Although I might be looking at this in completely the wrong way?

Please see below for the code im using to tie this together:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new DI.NLog.Logger());
        var form = kernel.Get<Form1>();
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

and the constructor of my form is where the logger is injected.

```
public Form1(ILog log)        
{
    InitializeComponent();            
    _log = log;
}
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to think about this:

First, make the form class implement `ILog`. What this means is that the form it self is a logging destination. When the logging methods are invoked on the form, write what you need to write to the RichTextBox control.

Now, the form itself is an `ILog` and it also depends on `ILog`. Also, I assume there is another `ILog` destination that you would like to log to, e.g., a Log4net adapter.

Here is how I imagine the object graph:

[image: Object Graph]

The arrow from X to Y means that X depends on Y, or that Y is injected into X.

The CompositeLog class is a [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) `ILog`, it depends on multiple `ILog` objects, and when it is invoked to log something, it broadcasts such request to all the `ILog` dependencies.

As you see from the graph, we have a circular dependency. This can be solved by using Property Injection.

We can use Property Injection inside the CompositeLog class like this:

```
public class CompositeLog : ILog
{
    private ILog[] logs;

    public ILog[] Logs
    {
        set
        {
            if(logs != null)
                throw new Exception("The logs dependencies has been set before");

            logs = value;
        }
    }

    public void LogInformation(string message)
    {
        foreach(var log in logs)
            log.LogInformation(message);
    }

    //Other methods here
    //...
}
```

Notice that this class does not take any dependencies on construction. We later can inject its dependencies via the `Logs` property.

If you are using [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/), your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) would look like this:

```
var compositeLog = new CompositeLog();

Form1 form = new Form1(compositeLog);

compositeLog.Logs = new ILog[]{ form , new Log4NetAdapter()};
```

I don't know if this can be done with NInject easily. The bindings are probably going to be complex. In such cases where [there are multiple implementations of a single interface, I think that DI containers fail](http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/08/23/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex-object-graphs/). I suggest you use Pure DI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yacoub, I think that you are right that for this particular problem it may be simpler to fall back on pure DI, however I don't find that particularly satisfying. If it's of interest to anyone else I did figure out a work around to get the same result that I was looking for: I created a logger to log to the console then rerouted the output to the richtextbox